# Uploading a file to Spring web service using Angular 7

Tags: angular, spring, file-upload, form-data

i am working on angular project, meanwhile i want to upload my image files to web server. I am using Spring web services to upload these files.
I have watched this code from a Youtube video.
HTML that i has used is:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h2>Entering a product</h2>
  <h4 *ngIf="submitted" class="text-success text">{{product_NAME.value}} has been submitted successfull.</h4>
  <form [formGroup]="insertProduct" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    {{insertProduct.value | json}}
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="product_NAME">Product Name:</label>
      <input required type="text" name="product_NAME" formControlName="product_NAME" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="product_PRICE">Sale Price:</label>
      <input required type="number" name="product_PRICE" formControlName="product_PRICE" class="form-control">
    </div>    
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="product_STOCK">Stock:</label>
      <input required type="number" name="product_STOCK" formControlName="product_STOCK" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="product_DESCRIPTION">Description:</label>
      <textarea required class="form-control" rows="5" formControlName="product_DESCRIPTION"></textarea>
    </div> 
    <div class="form-group">
      <select formControlName="productcategory_ID" class="custom-select" name="productcategory_ID" [class.is-invalid]="(hasError && productcategory_ID.touched)" (change)="validateType(productcategory_ID.value)">
      <option  value="default" selected>Select a Product Type</option>
      <option *ngFor="let type of productTypes" value={{type.productcatergory_ID}}>{{type.productcatergory_NAME}}</option>        
      </select>
      <small class="text-danger" *ngIf="hasError && productcategory_ID.touched">Please choose an appropriete type.</small> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="productimage_ID">Select an image:</label>
      <input required type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" formControlName="productimage_ID" class="form-control" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">      
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Insert product</button>
  </form>
  <!-- for button above [disabled]="insertProduct.invalid" -->
</div>
<!-- For displaying name of file.. -->
<script>
  // Add the following code if you want the name of the file appear on select
  $(".custom-file-input").on("change", function() {
    var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
    $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);
  });
  </script>
```

and typescript code for change event registered with input for file is:

```
onFileSelected(event){
    this.userFile=<File>event.target.File;
    console.log(event);
    console.log(this.userFile);

  }
```

and to subscribe the service i have used following code to send form data to it:

```
onSubmit(){
    const fd:FormData=new FormData();    
    fd.append('file', this.userFile); 
    console.log(this.insertProduct.value);
    console.log(fd);

    this.service.insertImage(fd)
      .subscribe(
        res=>console.log(res),
        error=>console.log(error)        
      )
}
```

the service class i am using in angular is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Product } from './Interfaces/product';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {

  // headers = new HttpHeaders({'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'})
  path: string="http://localhost:8080/productcategory";
  productPath: string="http://localhost:8080/product";
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
//Posting image using form-data
  insertImage(file: FormData){
    var path=this.productPath+"/image";
    return this.http.post(path, File)
                .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }

}
```

and now i am going to provide the service that i am calling in java spring is:

```
// posting image in local path
    @PostMapping("image")
    public String saveFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        String directorypath = "E:\\Faltu Setup\\Tutorials\\Angular.JS Learning Path\\Youtube Tutorials\\Pratices(ANGULAR)\\Project\\src\\assets\\Images\\ItemIcons";
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyy-hhmmss");
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Date date = new Date();
        String fileName = "";
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                String[] split = file.getOriginalFilename().split("\\.");
                String ext = split[split.length - 1];
                fileName = "File-" + dateFormat.format(date) + "." + ext;
                log.info(file.getName());
                log.info(file.getContentType());
                log.info(file.getOriginalFilename());
                log.info(fileName);
                if (Files.notExists(Paths.get(directorypath), LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
                    Files.createDirectory(Paths.get(directorypath));
                    log.debug("I am entered.");
                }
                Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), Paths.get(directorypath + "/" + fileName));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return mapper.writeValueAsString(e.getMessage());
            }catch(RuntimeException e) {
                return mapper.writeValueAsString(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(fileName);
    }
```

everything is ok, i thing now you had understood all code i am using but when i subscribe the service it displays:

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:190) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:109) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1135) [na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) [na:na]
```

while it gives the following same exception in console of browser:

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException
```

i tried my best but to no avail. waiting for your replies.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: image service is below /product so it is calling the right service, so don't you worry about that i am calling /image service under productpath.

Comment: Exception's message: `Current request is not a multipart request` so review your form and add `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Answer (score 0):

`Current request is not a multipart request` give hint that your request is not multipart request where your Spring Boot expects it. For that,

You have to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form.

```
<form [formGroup]="insertProduct" enctype="multipart/form-data (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```

Here you have File instead of a file. `change File to file` as below.

```
insertImage(file: FormData){
    var path=this.productPath+"/image";
    return this.http.post(path, file)
                .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
  }
```

Also, add following in `application.properties`. You can change value according to your requirement.

```
## MULTIPART (MultipartProperties)
# Enable multipart uploads
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
# Threshold after which files are written to disk.
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
# Max file size.
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=500MB
# Max Request Size
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=500MB
spring.servlet.multipart.location=E:\\Faltu Setup\\Tutorials\\Angular.JS Learning Path\\Youtube Tutorials\\Pratices(ANGULAR)\\Project\\src\\assets\\Images\\ItemIcons
```

Comment: thanks all of you for your precious time, but by following all above steps now it is giving me the exception in browser console like this `error: "Bad Request"
​​
exception: "org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException"
​​
message: "Required request part 'file' is not present"`

Comment: while when i am using form to print on console it gives the following value of that control holding file `C:\\fakepath\\Capture.PNG`

Answer (score 0):

Inside your service:

```
return this.http.post(path, File)
            .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
```

may be you should change File to file, bacause ts is case sensitive?